# Any idea with Merge a boxes

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need a idea how to merge like two column boxes(div, or table) without a space at left column.
I have a plan to show some div/tables with Two block, or more without a white space.
Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/glover/VN5R2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        div.container
        {
            width:30em;
            border:1em solid;
        }
        div.box
        {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
            width:50%;
            border:1em solid red;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">This div occupies the left half.</div>
        <div class="box">This div occupies the right half.<br>This div occupies the right half.</div>
        <div class="box">This div occupies the left half.</div>
        <div class="box">This div occupies the right half.</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not using `<table>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry my bad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.container
{
width:30em;
border:1em solid;
}
div.box
{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
width:50%;
border:1em solid red;
}

div.l{
float: left;
}

div.r{
float: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="box l">This div occupies the left half.</div>
<div class="box r">This div occupies the right half.<br>This div occupies the right half.</div>
<div class="box l">This div occupies the left half.</div>
<div class="box r">This div occupies the right half.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you still guessing what i think, i try to move bottom left box up to bottom end first top box. there where is a white space. Because i have a some with different height boxes.